# Extremely large amount of reallocated sectors

Tags: windows-7, bad-sectors, hard-drive-failure

Before anyone starts giving me links I have read many threads about harddrives and bad sectors.  I was just curious about anyway to prolong a read-only drive from death.

For months now one of my older harddrives (almost three years now) has been dying.  The first harddrive to die on me and it has been a pretty slow process
Nowadays, due to its age, I have had it hold movie and show backups.  With 3 terabytes in size, it does this kind of well.  It has 555gb left of space.

However, every few minutes to a few hours several more bad sectors are reallocated.  Putting the drive into a friend's computer who owns HDSentinel for a few days (while he moved all the files on it onto his server) we can see this in the log

```
11/24/2014 3:20:56 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34744 -> 34760
11/24/2014 3:15:51 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34736 -> 34744
11/24/2014 2:50:09 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34728 -> 34736
11/24/2014 2:40:01 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34720 -> 34728
11/24/2014 4:33:52 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34712 -> 34720
11/24/2014 3:22:53 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34704 -> 34712
11/23/2014 2:17:02 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34696 -> 34704
11/23/2014 11:24:39 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34680 -> 34696
11/23/2014 11:19:35 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34656 -> 34680
11/23/2014 11:14:31 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34648 -> 34656
11/23/2014 11:09:27 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34640 -> 34648
11/23/2014 10:59:18 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34592 -> 34640
11/23/2014 10:49:10 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34576 -> 34592
11/23/2014 10:23:49 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34568 -> 34576
11/23/2014 10:08:36 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34560 -> 34568
11/23/2014 9:48:19 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34552 -> 34560
11/23/2014 9:07:46 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34544 -> 34552
11/23/2014 8:27:12 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34536 -> 34544
11/23/2014 8:01:51 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34528 -> 34536
11/23/2014 7:26:22 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34520 -> 34528
11/23/2014 7:21:17 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34512 -> 34520
11/23/2014 7:06:05 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34504 -> 34512
11/23/2014 6:25:31 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34496 -> 34504
11/23/2014 6:20:27 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34488 -> 34496
11/23/2014 6:00:10 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34480 -> 34488
11/23/2014 5:39:52 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34472 -> 34480
11/23/2014 5:09:27 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34464 -> 34472
11/23/2014 4:59:19 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34456 -> 34464
11/23/2014 4:54:15 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34448 -> 34456
11/23/2014 4:18:45 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34440 -> 34448
11/23/2014 4:08:36 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34432 -> 34440
11/23/2014 3:38:10 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34424 -> 34432
11/23/2014 2:11:50 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34416 -> 34424
11/23/2014 2:06:46 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34392 -> 34416
11/23/2014 1:36:21 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34384 -> 34392
11/23/2014 1:31:16 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34368 -> 34384
11/23/2014 1:26:12 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34360 -> 34368
11/23/2014 1:11:00 AM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34352 -> 34360
11/22/2014 11:09:55 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34344 -> 34352
11/22/2014 10:54:43 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34328 -> 34344
11/22/2014 10:19:10 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34320 -> 34328
11/22/2014 6:46:12 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34312 -> 34320
11/22/2014 5:09:52 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34304 -> 34312
11/22/2014 4:19:10 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34296 -> 34304
11/22/2014 3:58:53 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34288 -> 34296
11/22/2014 3:18:19 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34280 -> 34288
11/22/2014 2:52:58 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34272 -> 34280
11/22/2014 1:41:33 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34256 -> 34272
11/22/2014 1:36:29 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34248 -> 34256
11/22/2014 1:21:16 PM,#5   Reallocated Sectors Count  34240 -> 34248
```

I ran fsutil on the drive just to give you a better idea of the drive.

```
F:\Users\Ethan>fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo d:
NTFS Volume Serial Number :       0x5e4a13d64a13a9b3
Version :                         3.1
Number Sectors :                  0x000000015d4c97ff
Total Clusters :                  0x000000002ba992ff
Free Clusters  :                  0x0000000008ac24ab
Total Reserved :                  0x0000000000000780
Bytes Per Sector  :               512
Bytes Per Physical Sector :       4096
Bytes Per Cluster :               4096
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    : 1024
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment : 0
Mft Valid Data Length :           0x000000004b540000
Mft Start Lcn  :                  0x00000000000c0000
Mft2 Start Lcn :                  0x0000000000000002
Mft Zone Start :                  0x0000000005c93fa0
Mft Zone End   :                  0x0000000005ca07c0
RM Identifier:        7730EB65-6112-11E2-BBDC-3085A9EE10D4
```

As I said early in my post, is there a "good" way to prolong a drive from dying?  Black Friday and Cyber Monday are just around the corner but I'd prefer to use this drive a little bit longer.  I'm a poor college student with very little to no money in my name so I have to make due with what I got.  The only thing the drive really has to do is read information for playback if I decide to watch a movie or show.  Is there anything I can do or is a cross the fingers situation?

Any help (even verification that I'm SoL) would be lovely

Comment: Even if you put it in read only mode, its still going to reallocate the sectors, they are not necessarily failing because they are being written to.  Every read to the HDD will continue to degrade the HDD.

Comment: I see.  So, no matter what is done the hard drive will still degrade until it completely dies, even if it is just reading.  The 'contents of these sectors were moved to the spare area', it's no guarantee that the state of those 'bad sectors' are reliable, right?

Comment: Pretty much;...